# .NET Webforms application slow response after short idle

Tags: asp.net, webforms, teradata, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application which loads data from Teradata. I've noticed that if a user idles on a page (as little as 5 minutes), the page will be slow to respond (up to 15 seconds). If the user is navigating through the application without idling, the performance is much faster (at most 1 second).

The application is sitting on IIS 8. Funny enough, when running the development version of the application locally via the debugger on Visual Studio, I've never encountered this problem and the application responds smoothly.

I've received the following suggestions, query optimization, setting session timeouts to 60 minutes instead of the default 20, and database indexing.

1. I've set the session time out to 60 minutes and the problem still occurs.
2. Some of the lookup tables used to populate dropdowns are at most 15 rows, and the performance is still slow. Even if i optimize the db using better queries or indexing I don't think the performance will improve.

Below is the most commonly used function used to retrieve datasets from the database. I am using Teradata.Client.Provider to access Teradata.

```cs
public DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sqlQuery, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            ds = new DataSet();
            TdConnection conn = new TdConnection(getConnString());
            using (conn)
            {
                ///Build the TD DB Command
                tdSqlStringCommand = new TdCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
                using (tdSqlStringCommand)
                {
                    //Create an instance for TD data adapter
                    TdDataAdapter adapter = new TdDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = tdSqlStringCommand;

                    ///Append the Parameters
                    AddTdParameters(ref adapter, parameters);

                    ///Execute the dbCommand

                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

I'm expecting the problem to be on the IIS side since running the development version through the debugger on Visual Studio gives me no performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the behavior you are describing, you might want to look at your application pool idle timeout behavior in IIS (Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Idle time-out action).

Two things can happen when an app pool hits its idle timeout.

- Terminate
- Suspend

If an app pool/worker process is set to terminate once it hits the idle timeout, then the first request after the timeout is reached has to wait for the worker process to start up, this is something that will take seconds if you are running .net code. I personally work with an application that takes about 20ish seconds to spin up from a cold start.

Someone at some point may have made terminate the default app pool behavior in an attempt to reduce server utilization. This happened in my organization and for good reason, but the perception of reduced performance resulted in much frustration until we realized what happened.

However, Microsoft was kind enough to add a much nicer behavior, Suspend.

[Here is the MS article on Idle Worker Process Page-Out, it explains the suspend behavior.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/idle-worker-process-page-out-in-iis85)

Basically, instead of killing the worker process and making it run from a cold start, swap it out disk. There is still a performance penalty, but it's nowhere near as bad as a cold start. In my organization we were seeing it take 2 or 3 seconds as opposed to the 20 seconds of a cold start.

It really improved resource usage. Instead of having to keep 20 app pools running all the time and consuming a ~1GB of RAM apiece, now our app pools can suspend and only take up a 1 to 5MB of RAM until we need it.

Hope that helps.